# Conditioning number of edges

Tags: graph-theory, summation, combinations

[image]

Found this problem in the math magazine and I can't seem to answer it.

Here we condition on the number k of edges in T that emanate from A. Note that n+1-k edges then emanate from B; As Observed earlier, precisely one vertex i is joined directly by both A and B

Ther are n choose k ways of selecting k for the special vertex i, there are then k* n choose k ways of constructing a spanning tree with k tree edges emanating from A. Since the situations for different k are mutually exclusive we obtain.
[image]

The reader is invited to show that the sume(1) does in fact equal n2^n-1

[hint: Start by differentiating the identity (1+x)^n = [image] with respect to x.]

Answer (score 1):

Use the hint and evaluate both sides in $x=1$. You obtain

$$D_x[(1+x)^n]=n(1+x)^{n-1} = \sum k \binom{n}{k}x^{k-1} = D_x\left[\sum \binom{n}{k}x^{k}\right]$$

Then

$$n2^{n-1} = \sum_{k=0}^n k \binom{n}{k}$$